# DBCP connection pool issue

Tags: java, jdbc, jdbc-pool

I have an application where I am using DBCP Connection mechanism and tomcat8.

```
 <Resource 
    auth="Container" 
    driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" 
    maxActive="5" maxIdle="1" maxWait="-1" 
    name="jdbc/XXX_DATASOURCE" 
    password="XXXXXX" 
    type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
    url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@host:1522:pos" 
    username="XXXX" 
    removeAbandoned="true" 
    removeAbandonedTimeout="60" logAbandoned="true"/>
```

It works for any `getConnection` request except for one method which runs for around 7 to 9 times then it stuck while returning the connection.

No idea how to debug, some one could help.
putting the method below

```
 public static String addInventoryForDealer(Order orderData, String status, String response)
    {
           response = "0";
           List<Material> materialDataList = null;
           Connection connection = DBCPContextListener.getConnection();
           CallableStatement cs = null;  
           ResultSet rs = null;
           String materialCode=null;
           String tempMaterialcode;
           DelegatingConnection del = new DelegatingConnection(connection);
            OracleConnection conn = (OracleConnection) del.getInnermostDelegate();
           StructDescriptor materialTypeDesc,materialSrNumTypeDesc,materialBundleTypeDesc;
           try {
                        materialTypeDesc = StructDescriptor.createDescriptor("MATERIAL_BUNDLE_DETAIL",
                                      conn);
                        materialSrNumTypeDesc = StructDescriptor.createDescriptor("MAT_SR_NO",
                                      conn);
                        materialBundleTypeDesc = StructDescriptor.createDescriptor("MAT_BUNDLE_TYPE",
                                      conn);
                        materialDataList = orderData.getMaterialDataList();
                        if(materialDataList != null && (!materialDataList.isEmpty()))
                        {
                               // array holding structs, where each struct is based on an array
                               //   with fields of Project object
                               STRUCT[] materialAsStructs = new STRUCT[materialDataList.size()];

                               STRUCT unitSrNumberStruct = null;
                               // for each Project object, create a STRUCT object containing its fields
                               for (int i = 0; i < materialDataList.size(); ++i) {
                                      Material material = materialDataList.get(i);

                                      //create a pipe seperated string for all bundles
                                      STRUCT[] BunitSrNumStructs = new STRUCT[material.getSerialNumberList().size()];
                                      for(int j = 0; j < material.getSerialNumberList().size(); j++)
                                      {
                                             Object[] bundleFields = null;

                                             //start JFT check if needed
                                             BundleData bundleData = material.getSerialNumberList().get(j);

                                             //create unit sr number structs
                                             STRUCT[] unitSrNumStructs = null;
                                             if(bundleData.getUnitSerialNumber()!= null && !bundleData.getUnitSerialNumber().isEmpty())
                                             {
                                                    unitSrNumStructs = new STRUCT[bundleData.getUnitSerialNumber().size()];
                                                    for(int k = 0; k < bundleData.getUnitSerialNumber().size(); k++)
                                                    {
                                                           Object[] unitSrNoFields = new Object[]{bundleData.getUnitSerialNumber().get(k)};
                                                           unitSrNumberStruct = new STRUCT(materialSrNumTypeDesc,conn,unitSrNoFields);
                                                           unitSrNumStructs[k] = unitSrNumberStruct;
                                                    }
                                                    bundleFields = new Object[] {bundleData.getId(),unitSrNumStructs};
                                             }
                                             else
                                             {
                                                    unitSrNumStructs = new STRUCT[1];
                                                    Object[] unitSrNoFields = new Object[]{bundleData.getId()};
                                                    unitSrNumberStruct = new STRUCT(materialSrNumTypeDesc,conn,unitSrNoFields);
                                                    unitSrNumStructs[0] = unitSrNumberStruct;
                                                    bundleFields = new Object[] {"",unitSrNumStructs};
                                             }

                                             //end JFT

                                             //Object[] bundleFields = new Object[] {bundleData.getId(),unitSrNumStructs};
                                             STRUCT materialBundleStruct = new STRUCT(materialBundleTypeDesc,conn,bundleFields);
                                             BunitSrNumStructs[j] = materialBundleStruct;
//                                           Object[] maertialSrBundleFields = new Object[] {bundleData};
//                                           STRUCT materialBundleStruct = new STRUCT(materialBundleTypeDesc,conn,maertialSrBundleFields);
//                                           materialBundleStructs[j] = materialBundleStruct;
                                      }

                                      //remove all zero
                                      materialCode=material.getMaterialCode();
                                      tempMaterialcode = materialCode;
                                      //tempMaterialcode = StringUtils.stripStart(materialCode, "0");

                                      System.out.println("material code"+tempMaterialcode);
                                 Object[] maertialFields = new Object[] 
                                               {tempMaterialcode, BunitSrNumStructs, material.getSerialNumberList().size()};

                                 STRUCT materialStruct = new STRUCT(materialTypeDesc,
                                                                   conn, maertialFields);
                                 materialAsStructs[i] = materialStruct;
                               }

                               // now you have all your Project objects ready to be saved in one go:
                               ArrayDescriptor maertialTypeArrayDesc = ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor
                               ("MATERTAIL_DETAIL_TABLE", conn); 

                               ARRAY arrayOfmaterials = new ARRAY(maertialTypeArrayDesc, conn,
                                             materialAsStructs);

                               System.out.println("orderNumber:"+orderData.getOrderNumber()); 

                               cs = conn.prepareCall("{call PROC_UPDATEINVENTORY(?,?,?,?,?,?)}");            
                               cs.setString(1, orderData.getOrderRefernceNumber());
                               cs.setString(2, status);//TODO decide status on bases of goods issued and received
                               logger.debug("status"+status);
                               cs.setArray(3, arrayOfmaterials);  
                               logger.debug("array:"+Arrays.asList(arrayOfmaterials));
                               cs.setString(4, "0");
                               cs.registerOutParameter(5, Types.DECIMAL); //error code
                               cs.registerOutParameter(6, Types.VARCHAR); //error msg



                               cs.execute();

                               materialDataList=null;

                               //fill material type and count only not material details
                               rs = cs.getResultSet();
                               //System.out.println(rs.getDouble(5));

                               //System.out.println(rs.getString(6));
                               if(cs.getInt(5) == 0)
                               {
                                   response = "SUCCESS";
                                     /* while(rs.next())
                                      {
                                          response = cs.getString(10);
                                          //material count and status for the dealer
                                          Material temp = new Material();
                                          materialDataList.add(temp);
                                      }

                                      orderDetail = new Order();
                                      orderDetail.setMaterialDataList(materialDataList);
                                      */
                               }
                               else 
                               {

                                   response = "FAILED";
                               }
                        }

                 }
                 catch(SQLException sqle){
                     logger.error("Exception Ocurred - " + sqle.getMessage(), sqle);
                        try {
                            conn.rollback();
                        } catch (SQLException e) {
                            logger.error("Exception Ocurred - " + e.getMessage(), e);
                        }
                        response= "FAILED";
                 }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    logger.error("Exception Ocurred - " + e.getMessage(), e);
                    response="FAILED";
                }

                 finally{
                        DBAccess.closeResources(conn, cs, rs);//TODO no parameter to pass for callable statement
                 }
                 return response;
           }
```

Comment: It would be better if you posted the method code which is causing the problem.

Comment: `maxWait="-1" ` is a prime suspect, see [the doc](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/configuration.html): "The maximum number of milliseconds that the pool will wait (when there are no available connections) for a connection to be returned before throwing an exception, or -1 to **wait indefinitely**."

Comment: Updated the post with the method